# How to send slack notification in Jenkins based on variable?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack, slack-api

I want to send some alerts if something happened in the middle of the build.
I'm planning to save it to environment variable.

I want to trigger Slack Notification based on this environment variable. 
It means that if the environment variable is there, I want to trigger Slack Notification.

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: maybe https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin

Comment: If you are using pipelines this could help: https://medium.com/@lvthillo/send-slack-notifications-in-jenkins-pipelines-using-a-shared-library-873ca876f72c

Comment: No, AS far as I know, the environment variable support is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, either by using slack webhook api directly either using 3rd party tools like Jenkins Slack plugin.